# MBProgressHUD hide from another class

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

I have a class that handles request to a webservice. When this start to fetch information from the service I create and add a HUD on another class view. Like this,

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:viewController.view animated:YES] retain];
```

When the loading is finished I call this,

```
[HUD hideHUDForView:viewController.view animated:YES];
```

I set the delegate to self,

```
HUD.delegate = self;
```

But I can not get it to remove from the view.

```
- (void)hudWasHidden {
// Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
[HUD release];
HUD = nil;
}
```

I want to start in one class to show on another while the first is fetching data from the webservice. Then hide i from the first class.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

OK now I set the delegate in the first class to:

```
HUD.delegate = viewController;
```

But where do I put:

```
- (void)hudWasHidden {
// Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
[HUD release];
HUD = nil;
}
```

Comment: did u ever get the answer?

Comment: Try to remove all huds for that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the delegate of your HUD to other class.

For example if i add the HUD in Class A and want to remove it from Class B then i have to set delegate of HUD to class B.

Comment: For some reason the HUD is added two times to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a completion block from your first call and work your way up once you got an answer from the webservice, to hide the HUD in the block.

Something long the lines of :

```
[self callServiceWithBlock:^(NSError *error){

//Your service has answered, you can now hide the HUD

    [hud HIDE:YES];
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Error : %@");
    }


}];
```